# Diagnose script error

Tags: scripts

I am trying to figure why I can no longer change my volume via a bash script.

I noticed that line 2. shows 29% which is what my volume currently is.
volume.rb 40 used to set it to 40%.

Can someone help me resolve this?

```
andyk_~/Downloads$ volume.rb 40
##Current status###########################################################
ID D  M  Vol Sink Name                                      Output
0.   no 39% pci-0000_00_01.1                              hdmi-stereo 
1.   no 0% usb-Microsoft_Microsoft___LifeCam_HD-5000-02  analog-mono 
2. * no 29% pci-0000_00_14.2                              analog-stereo 
###########################################################################
```

Comment: What exactly is this `volume.rb` script you're using? Please [edit] and clarify, best would be to add the cotent of your script to the question.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bhme0v7bu6rkq22/volume.rb?dl=0

Comment: Script too large to put here. Here is it's link. https://www.dropbox.com/s/bhme0v7bu6rkq22/volume.rb?dl=0

Comment: Please add the link to your question and rather use https://paste.ubuntu.com instead of dropbox.

Comment: thats ruby, not bash - you could try an contact the [author](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiyjNudv-vYAhVB_iwKHY8gCSgQFggpMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2Furiel1998%3Flang%3Den&usg=AOvVaw0NoNd5lG4jEjvYt43y8KQY) .